# windows phone push notification on tiles

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, live-tile, mpns

i would like the app that i have created on wp7 to display alerts on the live tiles. I was going to use push notifications to do this. So, whenever there is an alert, the app will produce a push notification and then the live tile would display the push notification alert. I have tried to  find sample codes on msdn and i have not found much. Does anyone know any code sample for wp7 that would help.thank you!

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has [extensive howto articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and sample code; there is even a [How to: Send and Receive Tile Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202970%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which sounds like it should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help to you: [Windows Phone 7 notifications](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/chapter-8-introduction-to-windows-phone-7-notifications-for-iphone-developers). I went to a Windows Phone camp and came away feeling that there are, in fact, very distinct notifications and you have to make sure you're working with the right type for the right job. That link covers the types and their purposes, but did want to give you a heads up on that.